# Where docker saves stopped containers generated files?

Tags: docker

I've created a container without the `-v`, saved a text file on it, closed the container and when it was opened again the file was still there. The question is: how? Where Docker stores this file on the host machine?

Steps to reproduce:

```
docker run -dti --name alpine alpine sh
docker exec alpine sh -c 'echo "Hello World!!!" > hello.txt'
docker exec alpine sh -c 'ls'
docker stop alpine
docker start -ai alpine
ls
```

Comment: `/var/lib/docker` on my machine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you create a container without the `--read-only` flag, a writable filesystem layer is created on top of the image (alpine in this case), so that the container filesystem is writable. That'll exist until you remove the container.

The location on the host system depends on the data root for Docker (default: `/var/lib/docker`) and the storage driver in use (likely `overlay2`). You can find the storage driver in use for your container and the data directories in the `GraphDriver` property.

```
docker container inspect --format '{{ .GraphDriver }}' alpine

"GraphDriver": {
    "Data": {
        "LowerDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/d71e8f30d831f1c72e883e8de3c7560b2a69751f942fe8d5e24b740699872953-init/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/31f665ee64e368e98d39a709dd8662bcf92726be0c992ccad07553e277fe754f/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/a19268faed5bf38f3ad574274c2062bc29fad9406938b63e50451eeba440b30b/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/52b4b93b90556b85eb8b8680e037b9ba5eaaedaf91a197b5270ab25d85cc43c1/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/27cbda99661de508ba2fd6aefe3b5f98a3ef75966742f6566b7313065f713da0/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/8f5c1f89ef130b85016f114dc5e7ccc410cc2a0def823dc65bf9dad15f76eb47/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/483646cdc089e9828767c8ce6895da362a56ea7fd35881f70aee996d71dbf70a/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/ebbdc64049110d1710755176a2fb061759e25c52b3f90da65e6ae2fbfd7dc4dc/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/756e3bb714cce5892ce43d59d11492a7b027a0fe37abae2d5770cebe59a70bc3/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/362674379f2d583a5572c1797aed2ff03eefa786a509e04913cfb94a16a774dd/diff",
        "MergedDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/d71e8f30d831f1c72e883e8de3c7560b2a69751f942fe8d5e24b740699872953/merged",
        "UpperDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/d71e8f30d831f1c72e883e8de3c7560b2a69751f942fe8d5e24b740699872953/diff",
        "WorkDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/d71e8f30d831f1c72e883e8de3c7560b2a69751f942fe8d5e24b740699872953/work"
    },
    "Name": "overlay2"
}
```

The `UpperDir` will contain just the changes you've made, including the `hello.txt` file in your example. You can do something like this to navigate to it.

```
cd $(docker container inspect --format '{{  .GraphDriver.Data.UpperDir }}' alpine)
```

Comment: Thank you! I found it in `/var/lib/docker/overlay2/afeea6719e88518dfb58a7cd16044b407902e0e2b487843d31a985aa7e7cda7a/diff` directory. I have another question. In my host machine, I changed the content of hello.txt but I can not see the new content in "real-time" inside the running container. Only when I re-started the container I could see the changed content. Did you know why the files are not connected with each other?

Comment: You shouldn't modify the graph layers directly. The view of the filesystem in your container is an accumulation of all the layers together, and visible in `MergedDir`. There's details on OverlayFS,  the `overlay2` driver, and those directories here: https://docs.docker.com/storage/storagedriver/overlayfs-driver/